# Bug in rep calculation when displaying privileges banner?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Privilege banner buggy? Or am I just confused?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72270/privilege-banner-buggy-or-am-i-just-confused)

Take a look at the picture below. I have 1498 rep, the FAQ page shows I have 99% of the rep needed to edit tag wikis, yet the banner is displaying on the page. Is this a bug, or a possible caching problem? (I have checked and I am not able to edit tag wikis)

[image]

Comment: I wonder if you hit 1500 for a second and then got downvoted to 1498. Based on how the notifications usually work, I'd guess that banner will stick around until you tell it to leave, regardless of whether you have the privilege it describes.

Comment: I thought that, but looking at my rep for this week I don't see any downvotes. http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/60456?Tab=Reputation&StartDate=2010-11-10&EndDate=2010-11-10

Comment: it could have been an upvote that was rescinded.

Comment: I wonder if you can keep triggering it. Go accept an answer to make 1500, and then unaccept and accept it a dozen times and see if you get a dozen identical privilege alert bars :)

Comment: @Michael: IIRC, Waffles said that you only see the same privilege notification once, ever, so I don't think that would work. It would be an interesting experiment, though. :)

Comment: I love how this question was asked a month before the dupe, and this was the one closed :)