# Privilege banner buggy? Or am I just confused?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges, notification-bar

On the main Stack Overflow site, I arrived and had a banner:
"Congrats, you've gained the privilege – create wiki posts and 3 other privileges"
This confuses me, because I only see two privileges listed at 100%. Is the banner just buggy?

Or is there a better place to see my privileges that the page linked to by that banner?

Comment: just FYI, he has 6 rep on the main site when he asked this question, and according to http://stackoverflow.com/privileges there are only 2 privileges that require 5 rep. Heck, create wiki posts require 10 rep.

Comment: One possibility is that you had 16 reputation for a moment, but then someone withdrew their upvote on an answer of yours. This would cause you to be alerted of privileges as if you had 15 reputation (which would announce 4 new privileges on Stack Overflow for a former 6 rep user). The banner does not update after this kind of event, so it would end up misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The banner was inserted in your message box when you had over 10 rep, then somebody changed their mind and took back the vote, putting you back at 6.

When we insert stuff into the message stream we mark that privilege as notified meaning you will never be notified about it again.

The only way to fix this is to walk all the messages in the message table and roll back the invalid ones and "un-notify"

A change that corrects the priv message for this edge case would be very complex, I am inclined not to fix it for now.

Comment: Since you can look at actual vote times, do you think delaying the insertion into the message stream would help? I.e., if someone made a mistake in voting, they might upvote then undo immediately.

Comment: Wow, that's a much more interesting answer than I expected! :-) Thanks!