# Why did I get congrats for a privilege too soon?

Tags: bug, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Privilege banner buggy? Or am I just confused?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72270/privilege-banner-buggy-or-am-i-just-confused)

I got a congrats message for a privilege I have not yet earned.  I am 1 point short of gaining this privilege.   Is this a bug?

Comment: What was the privilege? It would help to know where the bug is.

Comment: It probably is not a bug.

Comment: Which privilege and which account? Edit privilege on SO?

Comment: I got a similar message when I had 491 rep on SO. "You can now retag questions". (Requires 500 rep)

Comment: You probably had the points for a moment. For example, I use a touch device and sometimes accidentally up or down vote while scrolling. And take it back a few seconds later.

Comment: My hobby: upvoting posts by people who are on the brink of earning a new privilege, and then retracting those votes within the 5 minute window.

Answer (score 2):

The mechanism that awards privileges is not 100% in-sync with your actual reputation score. There are processes that run every few hours to recalculate privileges and badges earned, based on your reputation.

It's possible that your reputation was momentarily above the threshold for the privilege recalculation process to run, but then afterwards your reputation was reduced by some other event that took place in the system (such as downvotes, someone taking back an upvote, someone accepting an answer and then unaccepting your answer, etc.).

However, even though the banner notifications aren't in sync, the actual privileges are. For instance, the moment I was above 1000 reputation here, I could see vote counts on questions and answers, but the actual notification that I had earned this privilege didn't happen for a few more hours.